# Inkscape, how to set a white stroke around the image and wrap text around a circle

Tags: inkscape, vector, images

Inkscape on Debian. I'm trying to set white stroke around an image (external border only) but didn't find the way to achieve that. Also I need wrap text around a circle, on the top and bottom: how to to achive that?

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What have you tried, or what has failed? Is that a vector image or a raster image? If vector, how is it constructed? How do you want the border to appear? As an outer circle, a square, or something else? When you say "wrap around" do you mean you want the text to follow the curve of a circle?

Comment: Vector [svg](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/Black_Sun.svg). I mean white border as an outer circle. I meant wrap text around a [circle](https://i.postimg.cc/GmM2Nw0d/tt.png). I tried Select all >  'Ungroup", then tried edit outer circle and apply stroke, but this don't work as expected. Seems, 'Ungroup' doesn't ungroup all elements.

Comment: thanks for the update. I've added an answer now

Answer (score 0):

The first is relatively easy. Draw a white filled circle, and drag it to the bottom of the objects stack. Scale to the size you want.  Note that to scale an objet proportionally from the centre, hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> while you click and drag the control handles.

To get it lined up with the symbol, enable Snapping to Object rotation centres.

[image]

As for the text, you can type some text, select the text box and a circle, and then do *Text > Put on Path*.  You will need two circles, one for the top text, and one for the bottom text.

To flip the text for the bottom of the circle, use the *Put on Path* function as above, but then do *Object > Flip Vertical*

Since the text is fixed to the circles, you can rotate the text into position by simply rotating the circle. You can also scale the bottom circle to get the text in the correct alignment.

The text on the bottom of the circle will likely be a bit crammed, so you can increase the letter spacing to spread the letters out a bit.

An example

[image]

After you are happy with your design, you can select the circles which the text is attached to, and set the stroke to none.

Comment: Thank you. Its not clear about drawing a white filled circle. I tried vertical menu in the left 'Create circles, ellipses, and arcs (E)', but how to select and move that [circle](https://i.postimg.cc/QxJqLNk2/Screen.png)?

Comment: You can use the Ellipse tool to draw a circle. To move it, use Selector tool. If you don't know the basics of using Inkscape, this might just be too difficult a task for a raw beginner. There isn't enough room here to do a complete beginner tutorial, but there are many on youtube.

Comment: All the above actions, drawing circle, adding text are within the one layer? i.e. no needs to open a new layer?

Comment: @minto - you don't need to use layers in Inkscape - just drag to the bottom of the objects - or select an object and do *Object > Lower to bottom*.

Comment: There's an excellent channel on youtube called [Logos by Nick](https://www.youtube.com/@LogosByNick/search?query=inkscape%20basics). I highly recommend this for learning the basics of Inkscape. He also has a detailed tutorial for putting text around circles.  I've no affiliation with this channel.

Comment: Finally, how to remove from design all black color elements, leaving only white elements? (since it will be printed on black)

Comment: @minto You should ask that as a new question.